# When I POST to an array, only one variable is posting

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to POST two values, 'id' and 'subscribed', from a URL into an array. The 'subscribed' value is being retrieved correctly, however, only the first 'id' value is getting retrieved.

URL Query:

```
example.com/?
brands[0][id]=1&brands[0][subscribed]=true&
brands[1][id]=12&brands[1][subscribed]=true&
brands[2][id]=27&brands[2][subscribed]=true&
brands[3][id]=29&brands[3][subscribed]=false
```

Expected results:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [subscribed] => true
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 12
        [subscribed] => true
    )

[2] => Array
    (
       [id] => 27
       [subscribed] => true
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 29
        [subscribed] => false
    )

)
```

Current results:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [subscribed] => true
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [subscribed] => true
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [subscribed] => true
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [subscribed] => false
    )

)
```

I've tried changing 'id' to another word, thinking 'id' might be a reserved word, but that did not work either.

Any ideas as to where to continue looking to fix this problem?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that, do you have an online example?

Comment: I get a slightly different, but still wrong result using your code as posted. If I remove the line breaks, it works as expected.

Comment: Broken with linebreaks: http://codepad.viper-7.com/NN2HhS has an array key called `brands]`

Comment: You say "I am trying to POST two values" but this looks like a GET not a post, right?

Comment: It is a POST, I was just showing it like that to make it easier. Michael, your answer was it. I just needed to remove the line breaks, didn't even think of that... so simple. Thanks!